# problem read sqlite version 3 from assets folder in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I build sqlite by C#.net like this

```
SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;Version=3;");
if (!File.Exists("MyDatabase.sqlite"))
{
    SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");
    m_dbConnection.Open();
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farmakology(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,tabaghe TEXT,name TEXT,enname TEXT,img TEXT,farmaco TEXT,amal TEXT,balin TEXT,masraf TEXT,tadakhol TEXT,amozesh TEXT,avarez TEXT);";
    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Then I store some data to this sqlite and copy it to assets folder of my android project then use this code to read it:

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String ENNAME="enname";
    private static final String POSES_TABLE="farmakology";

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    public ArrayList<Poses> getPoses(){
        SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
        String[] columns={MyDatabase.ENNAME};
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM farmakology" , null);
        ArrayList<Poses> questionsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            Poses questions=new Poses();
            questions.enname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.ENNAME));
            questionsArrayList.add(questions);
        }
        return questionsArrayList;
    }
}
```

However, logcat shows this error (there is not such table)

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.toolha.pharmacology/ir.toolha.pharmacology.asli}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: farmakology (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM farmakology
```

where is problem?
how can fix it?

**EDITED**

I also use SQLiteOpenHelper but still not helped and not worked for me

```
public class SqlLiteDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String TAG = SqlLiteDataBaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/ir.toolha.pharmacology/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.sqlite";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "farmakology";
    private static final String COL_Name = "enname";
    private Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    }


    //This method is just retuning total no of recode in your table Getting single contact count
    public int  getDataCount() {
        String userRollNo = null;
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME ;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        return cursor.getCount();
    }


    public void openDataBase () throws SQLException {
        String path = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS | SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
    }

    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
        InputStream in  = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        Log.e("sample", "Starting copying");
        String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        File databaseFile = new File( "/data/data/ir.toolha.pharmacology/databases");
        // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!databaseFile.exists()){
            databaseFile.mkdir();
        }

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
            out.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        Log.e("sample", "Completed" );
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();

    }

    public void deleteDb() {
        File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
        if(file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
            Log.d(TAG, "Database deleted.");
        }
    }
    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try {
            File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
            checkDB = file.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return checkDB;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some errors in your Java code.

You have the database stored in your asset folder. So, before using it, you must copy it to the proper database folder. That can be done via `CopyDataBaseFromAsset()`. However, your code does not call that method.

So, I suggest to update your code as follows:

**SqlLiteDataBaseHelper.java**

This class is used to open the database only. You don't perform queries here. It should only manage the creation of your database.
I just removed some methods and updated the Constructor.

```
public class SqlLiteDataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = SqlLiteDataBaseHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/ir.toolha.pharmacology/databases/";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.sqlite";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "farmakology";
    private static final String COL_Name = "enname";

    public SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        if (!checkDataBase()) {
            try {
                CopyDataBaseFromAsset();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error creating source database", e);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
        // Do nothing here
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        // Do nothing here
    }

    public void CopyDataBaseFromAsset() throws IOException {
        InputStream in  = context.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
        Log.e("sample", "Starting copying");
        String outputFileName = DATABASE_PATH+DATABASE_NAME;
        File databaseFile = new File( "/data/data/ir.toolha.pharmacology/databases");
        // check if databases folder exists, if not create one and its subfolders
        if (!databaseFile.exists()){
            databaseFile.mkdir();
        }

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while ((length = in.read(buffer))>0){
            out.write(buffer,0,length);
        }
        Log.e("sample", "Completed" );
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        in.close();
    }

    public boolean checkDataBase() {
        boolean checkDB = false;
        try {
            File file = new File(DATABASE_PATH);
            checkDB = file.exists();
        } catch(SQLiteException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return checkDB;
    }
}
```

**MyDatabase.java**

Then, you create a new class which will be responsible to read the values from the database and convert to proper format (in your case, to an array list)

```
public class MyDatabase {

    private SqlLiteDataBaseHelper mSqlHelper;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) {
         mSqlHelper = new SqlLiteDataBaseHelper(context);
    }

    public ArrayList<Poses> getPoses(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = mSqlHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String[] columns={MyDatabase.ENNAME};
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM farmakology" , null);

        ArrayList<Poses> questionsArrayList=new ArrayList<>();

        // You need to move to first item before doing anything
        if(cursor != null) {
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    Poses questions=new Poses();
                    questions.enname=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.ENNAME));
                    questionsArrayList.add(questions);
                }
            }
            cursor.close(); // Don't forget to close the cursor.
        }

        db.close(); // Don't forget to close the database once your job is done

        return questionsArrayList;
    }
}
```

Most important:

1. You must copy the database from asset folder to the proper database folders (`/data/data/ir.toolha.pharmacology/databases/`)
2. SQLiteOpenHelper helps you to opening and closing your database.
3. An third class is necessary to open the database, read the values, close the database and return the result.
4. You can encapsulate everything in a single class. However, I think it is better to keep those codes separated in two classes.
5. I didn't test the code I suggested.. So, use with caution.. my intention here is just show the points that you should improve in your code.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use SQLiteOpenHelper instead of SQLiteAssetHelper , and create your DB in onCreate :

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.sqlite";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
    private static final String ENNAME="enname";
    private static final String POSES_TABLE="farmakology";
    string sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farmakology(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,tabaghe TEXT,name TEXT,enname TEXT,img TEXT,farmaco TEXT,amal TEXT,balin TEXT,masraf TEXT,tadakhol TEXT,amozesh TEXT,avarez TEXT);";

public MyDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(sql);
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to create my db in C# and then copy it into assets folder . I use SQLiteOpenHelper but still not work